# Ubuntu container can't find shell script

Tags: shell, docker, dash-shell

I'm new to Docker, and am trying a simple example of an Ubuntu container that runs a shell script.  I'm on Windows 10 with Docker 17.09.0-ce.

My shell script is simply:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "hello world!"
```

My Dockerfile is:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
WORKDIR /usr/local/bin
COPY shelltest.sh shelltest.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/shelltest.sh"]
```

I've tried various forms of ENTRYPOINT and CMD invocations, and none work.  They all fail with "no such file or directory".  When I change the entry point to "/bin/sh" and launch the container interactively, I can see the file /usr/local/bin/shelltest.sh, and it has execute permissions 755, so I'm at a loss to explain why this isn't working.  Here's what the file looks like in the container when the entry point is set to "ls -l /usr/local/bin/shelltest.sh":

```
ENTRYPOINT ["ls", "-l", "/usr/local/bin/shelltest.sh"]

d:\Dev\Docker\shelltest>docker run shelltest 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 32 Oct 29 16:32 /usr/local/bin/shelltest.sh
```

**What am I missing?**

Here are some things I've tried:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/shelltest.sh"]

d:\Dev\Docker\shelltest>docker run shelltest
standard_init_linux.go:185: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"


ENTRYPOINT ["shelltest.sh"]

d:\Dev\Docker\shelltest>docker run shelltest
standard_init_linux.go:185: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"


CMD ["/usr/local/bin/shelltest.sh"]

d:\Dev\Docker\shelltest>docker run shelltest
standard_init_linux.go:185: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes if you write your shell scripts in windows you get execution errors like that, try using `dos2unix shelltest.sh` or saving it as a Unix file, no DOS. If you can't do it manually (using notepad++, atom or sublime) try this link [this link](http://newline.nadav.org)

Comment: The file already has "x" permission (755), I've added the file attributes output to my question.

Comment: Sometimes if you write your shell scripts in windows you get weird errors like that, try using `dos2unix shelltest.sh` or saving it as a Unix file, no DOS. If you don't have access to that kind of tools try [this link](http://newline.nadav.org)

Comment: Please update your answer with this information, because that was the problem!  I used Notepad++ to save the shell script with Unix line endings, and now the container executes successfully with the ENTRYPOINT set to that script path.  Thank you!